# return size of table as MB not KB

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Using Postgres to return the size of a table

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('zlimitreacjed_1'));
```

returns '1632 kb'....is there anyway to return this value as MB as opposed to kb's?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Judging by the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html), pg_size_pretty automatically adjusts as appropriate. If you want to use megs regardless, you could just use

```
SELECT pg_table_size('zlimitreacjed_1') / 1024 /1024 || 'MB';
```

pg_table_size returns bytes, so just divide it by 1024 a bunch of times, depending on what you want (once for kb, twice for mb, thrice for gb and so on).

Comment: thanks for the reply but this doesnt working SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('zzbirmingham_march_1') / 1024 /1024 || 'MB');  fires the error ERROR:  function pg_size_pretty(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('zzbirmingham_march_1') ...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

Comment: @John no, don't use the pg_size_pretty function. Just use the pg_table_size, like I showed you.